# Codeigniter function array always returns no

Tags: php, arrays, database, codeigniter

Rather noobish question. Given the following code:

```
public function in_group($group)
    {
        $session = $this->CI->session->userdata('logged_in');
        $query = $this->CI->db->get_where('people_groups', array('people_id' => $session['user_id']));
        $array = array();
        foreach ($query->result() as $row)
        {
           $array = $row->group_id;

        }
        if ( $array == $group)

        {
            return 'YES';
        }
        return 'no';
```

}

The result is always no, when in fact it should be yes according to the database.

What i am trying to do is to check the people_groups table to see if the current user is in the requested `$group`. I have research as to how to use the arrays in the following way, but i fear i have done something rather noobish.

NOTE: The `$group_id` references the column in the table that stores the group id's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I descovered that i missed a section in the user guide to achieve what i wanted the correct code should have been:

```
public function in_group($group)
    {
        $session = $this->CI->session->userdata('logged_in');
        $query = $this->CI->db->get_where('people_groups', array('people_id' => $session['user_id']));

        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
        {
            if ( $row['group_id'] == $group)

            {
                return 'YES';
            }
            return 'no';

        }
    }
```

Thank you to the people who responded, I hope this helps other people making silly mistakes :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not inserting values into the array, so change this:

```
$array = $row->group_id;
```

to

```
$array[] = $row->group_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just change your query to select where there is a row with that user and group id, something like this:

```
$this->CI->db->select('*');
$this->CI->db->from('people_groups');
$this->CI->db->where('people_id', $session['user_id']);
$this->CI->db->where('group_id', $group);
$query = $this->CI->db->get();
```

Then you can just check if there is a result or not, instead of looping through all the results.